# Mac-address changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm facing a problem here, I was using this library [UIDevice with UniqueIdentifier for iOS 5](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5) to generate a unique identifier for iOS device, its just simple md5 hash of mac address. And everything was ok, I've published app in the appstore, and after some time I've decided to write small update. My app uses dedicated server for api, so identifying user is very important. But when I started my app after update (I was integrating TapJoy) - I had another mac address, and other unique identifier. I thought mac address cannot change, am I wrong? Same keeps happening in simulator and on the device.

Comment: Given what you've told us, it'd seem far more likely that your hash function changed than that the MAC address changed.

Comment: I didn't change source which is responsible for hashing. When I run approved app I get one identifier, when I run test version I get another=((

Comment: Same device, right? One version of the app produces one value when hashing the MAC address, another version produces a different value. You know the MAC address isn't flipping back and forth, ergo there's something different about the software.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmm. I've removed TapJoy library, and everything went back to normal. Now I see the difference, TapJoy somehow was overriding Mac address, and removing all colons from it. I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so i figured it out. Its all about TapJoy. Their library implements `[[UIDevice currentDevice] macadress]` method. Also, [UIDevice with UniqueIdentifer for iOS 5](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5) implements the same method. Difference between them - is colons in mac address. TapJoy implementation doesn't have them, when UniqueIdentifier does. And when you use both of this libraries at same time, it can cause issues. So be warned! What I did, was simply renaming method `[[UIDevice currentDevice] macadress]` in UniqueIdentifier lib, to `[[UIDevice currentDevice] macadress_colons]` and it did the trick.